# Faltings theorem and number of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The Faltings theorem states that the number of rationals over an algebraic curve is finite if the genus is greater than 1. The genus decreases by increasing the number of singularities. My question is this. Should one count only the rational singularities or all the singularities over the complex field?

Comment: The name is Faltings. What do you mean? Arithmetic genus (I assume, since you are talking about singularities) is a birational invariant, so it is in particular invariant under normalization. So it should not depend on the number of singularities, right? And what do you mean by should one count? Doesn't that depend on what you want to do or achieve?

Comment: I am referring to the geometric genus. This is defined as (d-1)(d-2)/2-s, where s is the number of singularities. By "should one count", I simply mean "how to count correctly the singularities?"

Comment: Okay, I see what you meant now. But I think there are a couple points that need to be clarified, so I will add it as an answer due to length restrictions in comments

Comment: @Pedro Hmm I think if $C$ is singular then it's not the case that its the arithmetic genus of its normalisation is equal to the arithmetic genus of $C$. See Hartshorne IV exercise 1.8.

Comment: @loch Thanks for your comment, I was wrong. I thought the arithmetic genus was birational invariant for all varieties based on [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Arithmetic_genus) link. I guess it isn't?

Comment: @Pedro I think it is true for smooth varieties over char $0$. For curves this is obvious because smooth curves are birational iff the are isomorphic to each other, and for surfaces this is proved in Hartshorne Corollary V.5.6.